# OpenRasta URI implementation issue

Tags: openrasta

I am implementing URI in OpenRasta for a resource in configuration file. This perticular resource is a child entity of multiple resources.
Parent and child is having one to many relation. All Parent Entities are having an int value via enum type in code.

Now I want to implement my URI like this :

{ParentEntityName}/{ParentId}/{ChildName}/{ChildId}

How can I implement this?? Do I need to make saperate configuration for each parent entity or there is a dynamic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a handler that takes all this and retrieve the entity that way.

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<Childresource>()
                 .AtUri("{ParentEntityName}/{ParentId}/{ChildName}/{ChildId}")
                 .HandledBy<Handler>()
```

and

```
class Handler {
  public ChildResource Get(string parentEntityName, int parentId, string childName, int childId) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now that said, if the child has an identifier on the server you can probably make things easier on yourself by just mapping the URI with an id.